# Compiling go with libicu on alpine linux

Tags: linux, go, ld, icu, alpine-linux

I am trying to compile a go project with a dependency on golang.org/x/text/cases which is failing with:

```
# golang.org/x/text/cases 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -licui18n.57
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/6.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -licuuc.57 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It is being built with go-1.8.3 in an alpine docker container.

The icu packages I've installed are:

- icu-libs-57.1-r3
- icu-57.1-r3
- icu-dev-57.1-r3

I've also tried with the these environment variables as well and it made no difference:

```
CGO_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/icu -L/usr/lib/
CGO_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/unicode -I/usr/include/layout
CGO_CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/unicode -I/usr/include/layout
```

No sure where else to look for what's wrong.

I do not need to use alpine specifically and was previously using only the compiled go binary (statically linked), but I have found having the distro available for runtime debugging invaluable.

Comment: Sure isn't GNU - but what does this have to do with the issue?

Comment: The point is that musl is a pretty limited version of a libc. Your program links against features of the glibc. Happy porting!

Comment: If forking the text package is an option, this can be resolved by removing the hard dependency to a version of icu which is only used for tests, explained here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/od8Obi9flDA/mtoQMc3FDAAJ - this circumvents lack of understanding of musl/ld on alpine.